# Copying an array to a smaller array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following problem when trying to cop an array into array.

Say my starting array is 15x11.

My desired array is 12x8.

I want it to work like so:

If first array is bigger than 2nd array, skip every second row/column until it has proper size.

So with my example:

Take first row, skip 2nd, take 3rd, skip 4th, take 5th, skip 6th, take the rest as it now fits.

Same for columns.

I'm trying to wrap it up into code with no success so far. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

EDIT: This is what I tried for columns for example

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                while (remcol > 0)
                {
                    n[i, j] = g[i, remcol - (remcol - k)];
                    k++;
                    remcol--;
                }
                n[i, j] = g[i, j + k];
            }
        }
```

K is 0 at start, and remcol is g.GetLenght(1) - n.GetLenght(1). Gis bigger array, n is smaller.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: I tried with declaring 2 variables, which are biggersize-smallersize, and then somehow fitting that into 2 for loops(which go over the indexes of smaller array). Then I tried to fiddle with smth along the lines while var > 0, smallerarray[i,j] = bigger array[i,j+1] for example for columns, but vs tells me I either go over the indexes, or it puts the wrong values. I probably have problem with how I coded the part after my helping variable reaches 0.

Comment: Did you try debugging your solution? Loops-based solution seems like the way to go here.

Comment: I've edited my post to show what Im doing

Comment: Again: did you try debugging your solution?

Comment: When I run with debugging, it stops and tells me that n[i, j] = g[i, remcol - (remcol - k)]; goes over the allowed indexes of n. But I can't see why.

Comment: @Ironowicz, try to post your clean code at https://dotnetfiddle.net/, so we may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int rowDif = g.GetLength(0) - n.GetLength(0);
int colDif = g.GetLength(1) - n.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < n.GetLength(0); i++)  
{
  int mappedRow = i * 2 <= 2 * (rowDif - 1) ? 2 * i : 2 * rowDif + ( i - rowDif + 1);
  for (int j = 0; j < n.GetLength(1); j++)
  {    
    int mappedCol = j * 2 <= 2 * (colDif - 1) ? 2 * j : 2 * colDif + ( j - colDif + 1);
    n[i, j] = g[mappedRow, mappedCol];
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I modified it a bit and it works. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this do the job? It copies arrays with dimensions n/2 <= g <= n*2. Test case attached. It uses standard loops and simply if statements for readability.

```
void CopydArrayScaled(int[,] g, int[,] n)
{
    int gRowSkip = g.GetLength(0) - n.GetLength(0);
    for (int nRowIdx = 0, gRowIdx = 0; nRowIdx < n.GetLength(0); nRowIdx++)
    {
        int gColSkip = g.GetLength(1) - n.GetLength(1);
        for (int nColIdx = 0, gColIdx = 0; nColIdx < n.GetLength(1); nColIdx++)
        {
            n[nRowIdx, nColIdx] = g[gRowIdx, gColIdx];
            if (gColSkip > 0)
            {
                gColSkip--;
                gColIdx += 2;
            }
            else if (gColSkip < 0)
            {
                if (nColIdx % 2 == 1)
                {
                    gColIdx++;
                    gColSkip++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                gColIdx++;
            }
        }
        if (gRowSkip > 0)
        {
            gRowSkip--;
            gRowIdx += 2;
        }
        else if (gRowSkip < 0)
        {
            if (nRowIdx % 2 == 1)
            {
                gRowIdx++;
                gRowSkip++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gRowIdx++;
        }
    }
}

void CopydArrayScaled2(int[,] g, int[,] n)
{
    int gRowSkip = g.GetLength(0) - n.GetLength(0);

    for (int nRowIdx = 0; nRowIdx < n.GetLength(0); nRowIdx++)
    {
        int gRowIdx = nRowIdx * g.GetLength(0) / n.GetLength(0);
        int gColSkip = g.GetLength(1) - n.GetLength(1);
        for (int nColIdx = 0; nColIdx < n.GetLength(1); nColIdx++)
        {
            int gColIdx = nColIdx * g.GetLength(1) / n.GetLength(1);
            n[nRowIdx, nColIdx] = g[gRowIdx, gColIdx];
        }
    }
}

void PrintArray(int[,] a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Destination dimensions: [{0},{1}]", a.GetLength(0), a.GetLength(1));
    for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (j != 0) Console.Write(",");
            Console.Write(a[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

void Test()
{
    int[,] g = new int[4, 4] { { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6, 7 }, { 8, 9, 10, 11 }, { 12, 13, 14, 15 } };

    int[,] n = new int[2, 2];
    CopydArrayScaled(g, n);
    PrintArray(n);

    int [,] n2 = new int[8, 8];
    CopydArrayScaled(g, n2);
    PrintArray(n2);

    int[,] n3 = new int[4, 4];
    CopydArrayScaled(g, n3);
    PrintArray(n3);
}
```

output:

```
Destination dimensions: [2,2]
0,2
8,10
Destination dimensions: [8,8]
0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3
0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3
4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7
4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7
8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11
8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11
12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15
12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15
Destination dimensions: [4,4]
0,1,2,3
4,5,6,7
8,9,10,11
12,13,14,15
```

Note: Added Version 2. It allows n and g to be arbitrary size, BUT does not adhere to the original question: skip each second row/column. For dimensions (n*2>g) the skip method gives strange results.